# DecimalFormat to format minutes to hours

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have time in minutes say some 900 minutes, i need to convert 900 minutes to hours which can be done by dividing with 60, but this has to be done using DecimalFormat some thing like

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("xxxxxH");
System.out.println(formatter.format(900));
```

The output should be 15H

I need to pass the formatter to some other methods(for formatting Y axis in a bar chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to pass the formatter to some other methods(for formatting Y axis in a bar chart)

I'll leave the implementation details as a learning exercise for you, but one straightforward way would be to create your own subclass of [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) that overrides the various [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format(double,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)) methods, does the math, and passes the resulting modified number off to the base for the usual formatting.

When implementing this, make your goal to be to allow the base `DecimalFormat` to still do as much of the work as possible.

As an option, you may choose to parameterize your division factor instead of hardcoding e.g. 60, which will give you a better chance to reuse your new class in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` will not perform that math for you. You could use `printf` and

```
int mins = 900;
System.out.printf("%dH%n", mins / 60);
```

or [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
int mins = 900;
System.out.println(String.format("%dH", mins / 60));
```

or [`TimeUnit.convert(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) like

```
int mins = 900;
System.out.println(String.format("%dH",
        TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(mins, TimeUnit.MINUTES)));
```

All three output

```
15H
```

Comment: i can use all the above to get the required format, but i need to pass the formatter to some other methods(for formatting Y axis in a bar chart)

Comment: @achuth Are you saying you need your own subclass of `DecimalFormat` that does this for you, so you can pass it on to some method that has a parameter of type `DecimalFormat`?  If that is what you mean, you should probably indicate that in the question.